# Как проверить наличие столбца в таблице дo его удаления?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть таблица `DICTIONARY_DDF`, в которой есть столбец `DDF_CODE`.

Есть куча SQL скриптов, которые выполняются в зависимости от внешних факторов.

Нужно написать SQL скрипт, удаляющий `DDF_CODE`, если он присутствует в таблице `DICTIONARY_DDF`, иначе просто выходить из скрипта (без ошибки).

Если с удалением проблем нет - `DROP DDF_CODE`, то как проверить наличие столбца?

Comment: Желательно определится с диалектом SQL, т.к. эталонных СУБД не существует. В руководстве к метке стоит - _Указывайте используемую СУБД_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В PL/SQL надо будет создать процедуру, как то так:

```sql
create or replace procedure dropColumnIfExists (tableName varchar2, columnName varchar2) is
begin 
    for r in (
        select 1
        from user_tab_columns
        where table_name = upper (tableName) and column_name = upper (columnName)) loop
            execute immediate 'alter table '||tableName||' drop column '||columnName;
            dbms_output.put_line (tableName||'.'||columnName||' droped.');
            return;
        end loop;
        dbms_output.put_line (tableName||'.'||columnName||' do not exists.');
end dropColumnIfExists;
/
```

Вызывать её можно так:

```sql
create table dictionary_ddf (id number, ddf_code varchar2 (16));
exec dropColumnIfExists ('dictionary_ddf', 'ddf_code')
```

> dictionary_ddf.ddf_code droped.

Comment: неужели в Oracle 12c / 18c до сих пор не добавили `IF EXISTS` фичу? ;)

Comment: Неа, и в 19c тоже нет.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не указали диалект *SQL*!  В *PostgreSQL* поддерживается
следующий синтаксис:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dictionary_ddf
      DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS ddf_code;
```

Comment: Желательно чистый SQL, но можно PL/SQL